# Report Builder 3.0 Count Parameter issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

new to SSRS,

Would have done the count in the SQL view, but issue I have is that I have a count, the count will have to be done in the Report Builder dataset. This is because I wish for users to change Start and End date parameters

I have a parameter count (filter) as 0 (this is the default), 1, 2, 3 ect when the report is run

I have the following as part of a data set

```
sum(case when Delivery_Code = 3 then 1
when  Customer_id <> Customer_id then 1 else 0 
end) as Count
```

the count is working

however I wish to say bring me back all customers first so >=0, (0 is the default value when report is first run) but when a users selects count of e.g 2 it filters to those

I have the following, but its not working

```
Having (sum(case when Delivery_Code = 3 then 1

when  Customer_id <> Customer_id then 1 else 0 

end) in (@Count) or (@Count) >= '0' )
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Just use `=` instead `IN` clause, since you have variable `@Count` which has only one single value

So,

```
Having (sum(case when Delivery_Code = 3 
                 then 1
                 when Customer_id <> Customer_id 
                 then 1 else 0 
             end) ) =  @Count;
```

Comment: no luck with this sorry, any more ideas please?, think issue is that I need it on the default value when first run 0, but when someone changes it

Comment: The issue I have is its a count, I have for other parameters in there WHERE section.  example like  ([Site] in (@Site) or '0' in( @Site)) (this when selected brings back the site of production, or is set to the default 0, which is all sites)...please help